# How to divide an array into two arrays so that in one there are rows where there are zeros and in the other non-zero rows

Tags: python, numpy, split

I try to divide the field so that in one caste there is a part of the matrix where there are zeros and in the other field there will be non-zero values.

I try to divide the field so that in one caste there is a part of the matrix where there are zeros and in the other field there will be non-zero values.

```
import numpy as np

C1_1=np.array([[ 0, -4,  6],
       [ 0, -5,  7],
       [-1,  0,  6],
       [-1, -4,  7],
       [-1, -5,  8]])
C1_B= np.split(C1_1, np.where(C1_1[:, 0]!= 0.)[0][1:])
print(C1_B)
```

output:

```
[array([[ 0, -4,  6],
       [ 0, -5,  7],
       [-1,  0,  6]]), array([[-1, -4,  7]]), array([[-1, -5,  8]])]
```

sp

```
C1_B[0]
array([[ 0, -4,  6],
       [ 0, -5,  7],
       [-1,  0,  6]])


C1_B[1]
array([[-1, -4,  7]])


C1_B[2]
array([[-1, -5,  8]])
```

required output

```
[array([[ 0, -4,  6],
           [ 0, -5,  7],
           [-1,  0,  6]]), array([[-1, -4,  7], [-1, -5,  8]])
```

so

```
C1_B[0]
array([[ 0, -4,  6],
       [ 0, -5,  7],
       [-1,  0,  6]])

C1_B[1]
array([[-1, -4,  7]
       [-1, -5,  8]])
```

So 2 parts is enough for me and not three
Can anyone advise me?

Comment: What is the difference between your ouptut and the desired one?

Comment: I adjusted my question to make it clearer

Comment: Why does the 3rd row go to the first array ?

Comment: And what if your column has more zeros and ones, e.g `0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1`

Comment: so they should also fall into special fields in a similar way as my example, ie 00 together -1-1-1 together 00 abbot together and -1 separately, but I do not know if such a situation will occur

Comment: Why does this row `[-1,  0,  6]` go to the first array then ? Isn't it -1 and go to the 2nd array ?

Comment: because the 0 is significant, I separate nonzero lines from zero lines

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
# check any zero in each row
has_zero = (C1_1 == 0).any(1)

# find the split between zeros and non zeros
split_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(has_zero)) + 1

# split on index
np.split(C1_1, split_idx)

#[array([[ 0, -4,  6],
#       [ 0, -5,  7],
#       [-1,  0,  6]]), array([[-1, -4,  7],
#       [-1, -5,  8]])]
```